# OWSAP ESAPI logging support in logback in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, logback, slf4j, owasp

Is there OWSAP ESAPI logging supported in logback for spring boot application? I did a lot of research but could not find much on this. I found out that `org.owasp.esapi` now supports this after this [PR](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/pull/446/files) . But this means that I will have to do away with logback. Is there a way that I can implement OWSAP ESAPI logging using logback? We are using `slf4j` logger that logback provides.

I looked at logback's maven [page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic) and there has not been any major release since 2017. So I am guessing that logback does not supports OWSAP ESAPI logging. Please correct me if I am wrong. If that is the case are there any alternatives I can use?

Also according to [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12649) spring-boot does not support slf4j 1.8 and above.If that is the case are there any alternatives I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out that `org.owasp.esap` actually delegates the actual logging to our existing infrastructure. So all I had to do is add the correct package and it automatically takes care of the logging via whatever config I have in logback.

Add the esapi dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Add the [ESAPI.properties](https://github.com/OWASP/EJSF/blob/master/esapi_master_FULL/WebContent/ESAPI.properties) file to `src/main/resources/`. This file contains the config properties for the ESAPI logger. Since I was using Slf4j looger, I set `ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory` in the file.

Now we can use the ESAPI logger for logging which internally will use the Slf4j logger. As the function definition of the ESAPI logger has an extra argument I had to update all the logger functions accordingly.

Comment: This was very helpful. One thing I noticed with ESAPI logging is the event parameter in the log statement causes the event type to be printed to the log and also the full application name and class name from where the log originates i.e. EVENT UNSPECIFIED -> /Application Name/my.package.name.Class. Do you know if there is any way to turn off the printing of the application name and class?

Answer (score 2):

For me, the solution was:

1. Add the next code to my `pom.xml`

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
   ```
2. Add `ESAPI.properties` and `validation.properties` files to `src/main/resources/`, I took them from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202459/esapi-with-spring-mvc), of [Vaquar Khan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202459/esapi-with-spring-mvc/57234336#57234336).
3. Update the property `ESAPI.Logger` in the file `ESAPI.properties` with [this code of AshwinSreekumar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59425709/owsap-esapi-logging-support-in-logback-in-spring-boot/59981389#59981389):

   ```
    ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory
   ```

I hope it will help you, because in my case, I had to do some extra steps to make it work.